# Side input of size around 50Mb causing long GC pause

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

- We are running Beam application on Flink cluster with side inputs of size 50Mb.

  - Side input refresh ( Pull from external data source ) based on the notification sent to the notification topic in Kafka.
- As the application progress due to side input Full GC happening often and each GC taking ~30 sec which pauses task manager to send heart beat to the Master.
- After consecutive heartbeat miss , master assuming  worker is dead and  start reassigning the jobs , results restarting of application.
- We tried removing Side input , application works fine.

Questions :

- Is there any limitation on size of side input in Apache Beam side input ?
- I have created side input map using asSingleton() , is going to create  seprate copy for each task ? I have given 15 parallelism. is it going to create 15 copy in a JVM ( assuming all tasks assigned to same worker )?
- What is alternative for side inputs?

This is sample pipeline :

```
public class BeamApplication {
public static final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();
    options.as(FlinkPipelineOptions.class).setRunner(FlinkRunner.class);
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<Map<String, Double>> sideInput = pipeline
            .apply(KafkaIO.<String, String>read().withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                    .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class).withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .withTopic("testing"))
            .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KafkaRecord<String, String>, Map<String, Double>>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) {
                    KafkaRecord<String, String> record = processContext.element();
                    String message = record.getKV().getValue().split("@@")[0];
                    String change = record.getKV().getValue().split("@@")[1];
                    if (message.equals("START_REST")) {

                        Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
                        Map<String,Double> changeMap = new HashMap<>();

                        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/config-service/currency");

                        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request)) {
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
                            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                            CurrencyDTO jsonObject = objectMapper.readValue(responseString, CurrencyDTO.class);
                            map.putAll(jsonObject.getQuotes());
                            System.out.println(change);
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            Double db = rand.nextDouble();
                            System.out.println(db);
                            changeMap.put(change,db);
                            entity.getContent();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        processContext.output(changeMap);
                    }
                }
            }));
    PCollection<Map<String, Double>> currency = sideInput
            .apply(Window.<Map<String, Double>>into(new GlobalWindows())
                    .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
                    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO).discardingFiredPanes());

    PCollectionView<Map<String, Double>> sideInputView = currency.apply(View.asSingleton());

    PCollection<KafkaRecord<Long, String>> kafkaEvents = pipeline
            .apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read().withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                    .withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class).withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                    .withTopic("event_testing"));

    PCollection<String> output = kafkaEvents
            .apply("Extract lines", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KafkaRecord<Long, String>, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext processContext) {
                    String element = processContext.element().getKV().getValue();

                    Map<String, Double> map = processContext.sideInput(sideInputView);
                    System.out.println("This is it : " + map.entrySet());
                }
            }).withSideInputs(sideInputView));

    pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Kiran, can you share some details on how often does refresh happen, version of beam you're using and sample pipeline if possible?

Comment: Currently in week  one or twice  we are updating the side inputs. Side inputs are fetched from external service  and feed as  Map
Beam Version : 1.8
Flink version : 1.7.2

Comment: Pipeline logic :
1  main stream -->We have some events consuming from kafka
2. For side inputs we have some kafka topic called "notification topic", here we ll send some predefined notification , beam application reads this notification and loads the side inputs from  external service ( by hitting APIs). All data feed as Map (using asSingleton()  ).

Comment: @MikhailGryzykhin I have added sample pipeline code.

Answer (score 1):

What state-backend are you using?

If i'm not mistaken, side inputs are implemented as state in Flink. If you're using [MemoryStateBackend](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/state_backends.html#the-memorystatebackend) as state-backend, you might indeed reach pressure on you memory consumption.

Also, the processing of events will block until that side input is ready, buffering events. If preparing the side input take long time or the rate of incoming events is high, you might reach memory pressure.

Can try an alternative state-backend? Preferably [RocksDBStateBackend](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/state_backends.html#the-rocksdbstatebackend), it holds in-flight data in a RocksDB database instead of in-memory.

It's difficult to guess what's the issue. I would recommend monitoring memory related metrics - see a good post on that [here](https://flink.apache.org/news/2019/02/25/monitoring-best-practices.html).

You could also run profiling on the Task Managers and analyse the dumps - see [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/application_profiling.html#analyzing-out-of-memory-problems)

Is the memory increasing also if you only publish the first message to "testing" topic?

Maybe to isolate the problem I would use a simpler side-input. Remove the HTTP call and make the data static. Maybe a periodic triggered one instead of Kafka:

`GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(5L))`

Comment: - I am using  RocksDBStateBackend  only , job runs for  5-6 days  then suddenly GC Issue starts . If i run without side input it runs fine without any failure.